# Maximizing $ \frac {y + z + yz}{\left( 1 + y + z \right)^2} $

Tags: inequality

I was solving a WOOT Problem of the Day and I boiled the problem down to finding the maximum value of $$ \frac {y+z+yz}{\left( 1 + y + z \right)^2}. $$Intuitively, this seems to occur when $y=z$, since $y$ is symmetric, and after that, it is easy to find that $$ \frac {y+z+yz}{\left( 1 + y + z \right)^2} \le \frac {1}{3}. $$This seems "intuitive" but is not a proof. Any ideas for a formal proof?

Comment: Presumably you are restricting $y,z$ to be positive?

Comment: What basis do you have for your intuition apart from wishful thinking?

Comment: @almagest Yes. $\mathrm{}$

Comment: Suppose we take $y=1/1000,z=1000$, then we get about 1/1001. What restrictions are you placing on $y,z$ if any?

Comment: @almagest We want the maximum, not the minimum. There is a unique maximum.

Comment: Well, it would help if you changed the $\ge$ to $\le$

Comment: @almagest Oh whoops, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the new variables $u=y+z, v=yz$.  The old conditions of $y,z>0$ translate to $u,v>0$.  However, for any fixed $u$, the variable $v$ must lie in $(0,(u/2)^2]$, where the latter is achieved when $y=z$.

Thus, to maximize $\frac{u+v}{(1+u)^2}$, we set $v=(u^2/4)$, which gives the expression $$\frac{u+u^2/4}{(1+u)^2}$$

In particular this proves that $y=z$ at the maximum, which is indeed $1/3$.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the reasoning: it is true that for fixed $u$, the expression is at most $\frac{u+\frac{u^2}4}{(1+u)^2}$, but this does not imply that the maximum is attained for $y=z$. It is a priori possible that some other $u$ yields an even bigger expression, while $y\neq z$. For example, compare with finding the maximum of $2x$: this is at most $1+x^2$ with equality if $x=1$, but that does not imply that the maximum is attained for $x=1$.

Comment: The reason the maximum is attained for $y=z$ is by maximizing $yz$ over fixed  $y+z$ equal to a positive constant (and $y,z>0$).  This is a simple optimization problem over a line segment.

Comment: It was really confusing with the example of $2x\leq1+x^2$ in mind, but I can see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{y+z+yz}{(1+y+z)^2}=\frac{(1/4) (2 y-z-1)^2+(3/4) (z-1)^2}{3(1+y+z)^2}\ge 0.$$
The equality is attained when $y=z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the derivatives of $$F=\frac {y+z+yz}{\left( 1 + y + z \right)^2}$$ you have, after simplifications $$F'_y=\frac{-y (z+1)+z^2+1}{(y+z+1)^3}$$ $$F'_z=-\frac{y^2-2 y (2 z+1)+(z-2) z+3}{(y+z+1)^4}$$ Using $F'_y=0$ gives $y=\frac{z^2+1}{z+1}$ and the numerator of $F'_z$ simplifies to $$(1+z+z^2)(z^2+2 z-1)=0$$ So the solutions are  $$y=2 \left(-1-\sqrt{2}\right),z=-1-\sqrt{2},F=\frac{1}{18} \left(1-3 \sqrt{2}\right)$$ $$y=2 \left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right),z=-1+\sqrt{2},F=\frac{1}{18} \left(1+3 \sqrt{2}\right)$$